# Do I need to include #!/usr/bin/perl line in Perl script on Windows?

Tags: perl

I just installed ActivePerl on Windows and have begun to learn Perl. In the book that I'm reading, the first code example is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;

say "Hello, world!";
```

Since I'm on Windows, I was wondering if I need to include the first line?

I deleted the first line, and the program worked fine without it.

Is this line used just on Unix systems?

Comment: I believe Apache will use it (in which case it would need to be `#!c:\...`)

Comment: For Apache, specifying the script interpreter in the configuration file works well: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#scriptinterpretersource

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want the script to be portable to UNIX and Cygwin, keep the shebang line.  Even on Windows where the OS doesn't use it to determine how to run the file, Perl will still parse switches written there, such as

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

which turns warnings on by default (like `use warnings;` but global).

Comment: > Perl will still parse switches written there -- is this documented somewhere?

Comment: [`perlrun`](http://p3rl.org/perlrun): "The `#!` line is always examined for switches as the line is being parsed."

Comment: If portability is an issue, you should use `#!/usr/bin/env perl` as perl is not always installed in /usr/bin

Comment: BTW, is there a special name for this first line that tells the shell which interpreter to use?  is it correct to call it the `interpreter directive`?

Comment: @foampile You can call it an [interpreter directive](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/dict/terms/interpreter_directive), but it's more commonly referred to as a shebang for the two initial characters # (hash) and ! (bang).

Comment: if we write #!/usr/bin/perl in the middle of script what will happen? Will it throw an error

Comment: @Nitesh If you use [`perl -x`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-x*), Perl will search through the file to find the shebang line, load additional arguments from it, and begin execution from there.  Otherwise it will start executing from the top of the file, and shebangs in the middle are ignored like all other comments.

Comment: @ephemient Can I put this line, like `#!/usr/bin/perl` not the first in the document but after other comments?

Answer (score 7):

No, not in this particular case. The shebang line is used by shells in UNIX-like systems to locate the executable for scripts, which can generally be in any language.

Windows tends to use file extension associations for this purpose. For example, it may associate all `*.pl` files to be run with the Active Perl executable.

Perl itself *will* scan the line to get flags and such, so it's not totally useless in general.

Answer (score 3):

That line is used by the shell in UNIX systems, in windows is not needed, but is a good idea to still include it and keep your program more portable