# Multiple server sites with multiple #!perl requirements

Tags: apache, perl

I'm JUST starting with perl cgi, with an upload target of godaddy (I'm developing on a usW7 box with the XAMPP suite.  I know perl at a medium level.  I've come from an asp perl environment.

In cgi-perl you she-bang to point to the perl exec.  On my usW7 box, it's
`#!C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe`  I'll wager it is not so on godaddy.

Question is... how do you handle this #! construct in a way that allows an upload to godaddy without an subsequent edit.  I don't want to sed every time I move a file.  Any suggestions would be helpful.  Thank you.

(I was thinking of moving the perl exec to a usW7 directory that mimicked the godaddy path, but there is that drive letter thing.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059806/do-i-need-to-include-usr-bin-perl-line-in-perl-script-on-windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2036584/100754

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2036874/100754

Comment: 'There is no portable shebang line. '   got it.

Comment: I did the  ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict thing and installed a registry entry of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pl\Shell\ExecCGI\Command  (Default) C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe  ( Aside.  The strawberry is in there to support perl DBI.  Needed libmysql__.dll.  It's like xampp is out to get this perl user.)  Thanks for the links.